# ExecJS error when attempting to push to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I get this error when attempting to push to heroku:

```
rake aborted!
   ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected character '#' (line: 11438, col: 0, pos: 322768)
```

What does this mean, how do I fix it, and how do I locate the line/col # in order to find the error?

Comment: what's included in your `Gemfile`, execjs?

Comment: execjs is not included, does it need to be?

Comment: @JoeSmith not sure, include `therubyracer` and check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you drop the ".coffee" extension from a JS file (e.g., "users.js.coffee")? If so, pre-compiling won't work since the original coffee file has `#` for its comments, and `#` is not recognizable in JS.

Comment: This sounds very possible I will check it out